# Android: proGuard tutorial to specify exclusion and inclusion from obfuscation

Tags: android, obfuscation, proguard

I like to know if there's a cmprehensive tutorial on using proGuard for Android projects?

Particularly, I like to learn how to specify which class to exclude (for all include mode), include (for all exclude mode) for obfuscation and also if I can exclude jar libraries and library project and other dependencies to exclude from proGuard obfuscation.

Basically I like learn from some resources to get some practical fine grain customization of proGuard for use with Eclipse Android development.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Have you taken a look at the [official ProGuard documentation on SourceForge](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/)? There's a separate section on [Android Applications](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html#androidapplication). Most of what you are asking is not Android specific though and the official documentation should have you covered. Exclusion patterns are documented in the the [Keep options](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/usage.html#keepoptions). Obfuscation of libraries are documented [here](http://proguard.sourceforge.net/#manual/examples.html).

Also, a lot of third party libs (and Android library projects) specifically cover ProGuard options in their documentation (take a look at [Otto](http://square.github.io/otto/), [HockeyApp](http://support.hockeyapp.net/kb/client-integration-android/hockeyapp-and-proguard) or [Google Play services](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) for examples).